# Trigger Syntax Error With IF Statements

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working in PHPMyAdmin and I am trying to add a trigger. I'm having trouble getting the trigger to work because of the syntax error (listed underneath the trigger code).

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER new_sub 
AFTER INSERT ON subscriptions 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF NEW.cancelled = 0 THEN
IF NEW.plan = 'pro' THEN
  UPDATE statistics
    SET statistics.premier_today = statistics.premier_today +1,
        statistics.premier_this_week = statistics.premier_this_week+1,
        statistics.premier_this_month = statistics.premier_this_month+1,
        statistics.premier_all_time = statistics.premier_all_time+1,
        statistics.revenue_today = statistics.revenue_today + 8,
        statistics.revenue_this_week = statistics.revenue_this_week +8,
        statistics.revenue_this_month = statistics.revenue_this_month +8;
END IF;
IF NEW.plan = 'single-event' THEN
  UPDATE statistics
    SET statistics.single_event_today = statistics.single_event_today +1,
        statistics.single_even_this_week = statistics.single_event_this_week +1,
        statistics.single_event_this_month = statistics.single_event_this_month +1,
        statistics.single_event_all_time = statistics.single_event_all_time +1,
        statistics.revenue_today = statistics.revenue_today + 25, 
        statistics.revenue_this_week = statistics.revenue_this_week +25,
        statistics.revenue_this_month = statistics.revenue_this_month +25,
        statistics.revenue_all_time = statistics.revenue_all_time +25;
END IF;
END IF;
END;$$
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 29

Comment: Do you have a `delimiter` statement before the stored procedure (`delimiter $$`)?

Comment: I didn't at first. I went ahead and made that modification, and I got another error that I posted above (UGH!). Getting closer, but still not quite there. Thanks for all your help though so far, you've been a great help. If you have any other ideas let me know.

Comment: The last two lines should be `end;` and then `delimiter $$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` is used in selects.  You would use `if` in a trigger.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.cancelled = 0 THEN
    IF NEW.plan = 'pro' THEN
      UPDATE statistics
        SET statistics.premier_today = statistics.premier_today +1,
            statistics.premier_this_week = statistics.premier_this_week+1,
            statistics.premier_this_month = statistics.premier_this_month+1,
            statistics.premier_all_time = statistics.premier_all_time+1,
            statistics.revenue_today = statistics.revenue_today + 8,
            statistics.revenue_this_week = statistics.revenue_this_week +8,
            statistics.revenue_this_month = statistics.revenue_this_month +8;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.plan = 'single-event' THEN
      UPDATE statistics
        SET statistics.single_event_today = statistics.single_event_today +1,
            statistics.single_even_this_week = statistics.single_event_this_week +1,
            statistics.single_event_this_month = statistics.single_event_this_month +1,
            statistics.single_event_all_time = statistics.single_event_all_time +1,
            statistics.revenue_today = statistics.revenue_today + 25, 
            statistics.revenue_this_week = statistics.revenue_this_week +25,
            statistics.revenue_this_month = statistics.revenue_this_month +25,
            statistics.revenue_all_time = statistics.revenue_all_time +25;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, I get a syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NEW.cancelled = 0 THEN
    IF NEW.plan = 'pro' THEN
      UPDATE statistics
 ' at line 2

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with the rest of the trigger definition.  You should edit your question and insert the entire definition.

Comment: I went ahead and replaced it with my entire definition and posted the error

Comment: The problem may just be the lack of semicolons.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added them after all END if statements. Now I have a new error(updated main post)

Comment: [RTFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html): "if you use the mysql program to define a trigger that executes multiple statements, it is necessary to redefine the mysql statement delimiter so that you can use the ; statement delimiter within the trigger definition." See the example after the quote.